# doom emacs "Symbol's function definition is void: make-treemacs-theme"

Tags: doom, treemacs

I'm using doom emacs with current commit `c83e5e75e24706a0d6c15f3156d33b1c4f9dc365`.

When I do `SPC o p` I get error

> Symbol's function definition is void: make-treemacs-theme

Below is the screenshot -

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like another duplicate question. Hope someone has time to search for it...

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/309) help?

Comment: It might help if you specified what command the key sequence `SPC o p` is bound to: my guess is that the majority of Emacs users here do not use Doom, so you unnecessarily limit the set of people who might be able to answer by making your question so Doom-specific that only Doom users can answer it. In my case, I don't use Doom and I'm *NOT* going to install it just to find out what `SPC o p` is bound to: but if you told us what it is bound to, I (and others) might be able to help more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me:

```
~/.emacs.d/bin/doom build
```

Doing `doom build` recompiles and symlinks all installed packages.

I figured this out after seeing [a comment on a Github issue](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/309#issuecomment-650339955) about this exact error:

> This is caused by lsp-treemacs byte-compiled against old treemacs.

Comment: it throws `(error . "Invalid value (1 single-branch) of depth for https://github.com/emacs-straight/project.git")` error for me